# readHTMLTable and rvest not working for HTML Table scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I've been attempting to scrape the data from a HTML table with issues.

```
url <- "http://www.njweather.org/data/daily"
Precip <- url %>%
    html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="dataout"]') %>%
    html_table()
```

this returns:

> ```
> Warning message:
>     'html' is deprecated. Use 'read_html' instead. See help("Deprecated")
> ```

and a Precip List with no values in it.

I also attempted to use the `readHTMLTable()` function:

```
readHTMLTable("http://www.njweather.org/data/daily", header = TRUE, stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

this returns another empty list.

Comment: The site has a button to download a CSV, which is the easy option here.

Comment: I know, but because of circumstances involving restrictions on my computer I was hoping to avoid having to download the csv file daily.  I have tried the RSelenium package but it requires administrative privileges that I do not have.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that "Save to CSV" is a shockwave/flash control that just extracts the JSON content from the page, so there's no way to call that directly (via URL) but it would be clickable in a Firefox RSelenium web drive context (but…ugh!).

Rather than use RSelenium or the newer webdriver packages, might I suggest some `gsub()` node content surgery that then uses `V8` to evaluate the content:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(readr)
library(V8)

ctx <- v8()

pg <- read_html("http://www.njweather.org/data/daily")

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//script[contains(., '#dtable')]") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  gsub("^.*var json", "var json", .) %>% 
  gsub("var dTable.*", "", .) %>% 
  JS() %>% 
  ctx$eval()

ctx$get("json")$aaData %>% 
  type_convert() %>% 
  glimpse()
## Observations: 66
## Variables: 16
## $ city                 <chr> "Berkeley Twp.", "High Point Monument", "Pequest", "Haworth", "Sicklerville", "Howell"...
## $ state                <chr> "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "N...
## $ date                 <date> 2016-10-19, 2016-10-19, 2016-10-19, 2016-10-19, 2016-10-19, 2016-10-19, 2016-10-19, 2...
## $ source               <chr> "Mesonet", "SafetyNet", "Mesonet", "Mesonet", "Mesonet", "Mesonet", "Mesonet", "Mesone...
## $ DT_RowId             <int> 1032, 1030, 1029, 1033, 1034, 3397, 1101, 471, 454, 314, 299, 315, 316, 450, 317, 3398...
## $ temperaturemax_daily <int> 84, 73, 84, 85, 86, 85, 87, 81, 83, 83, 83, 83, 80, 81, 84, 86, 84, 72, 85, 85, 85, 84...
## $ temperaturemin_daily <int> 65, 63, 56, 65, 63, 66, 66, 64, 63, 66, 62, 64, 66, 62, 62, 65, 66, 67, 62, 64, 65, 62...
## $ dewpointmax_daily    <int> 68, NA, 65, 67, 68, 68, 68, 65, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 70, 67, 67...
## $ dewpointmin_daily    <int> 63, NA, 56, 60, 62, 63, 61, 55, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 62, 62, 61, 65, 61, 63, 62, 61...
## $ relhumidmax_daily    <int> 94, NA, 99, 94, 96, 91, 92, 90, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 102, 93, 88, 94, 99, 94, 94, 9...
## $ relhumidmin_daily    <int> 50, NA, 39, 45, 48, 51, 43, 41, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 51, 46, 49, 83, 51, 51, 48, 48...
## $ pressuremax_daily    <dbl> 29.97, NA, 29.97, 29.96, 30.02, 30.03, 29.99, 30.04, NA, NA, 30.01, 30.04, NA, 30.00, ...
## $ pressuremin_daily    <dbl> 29.86, NA, 29.86, 29.84, 29.91, 29.90, 29.88, 29.90, NA, NA, 29.91, 29.95, NA, 29.88, ...
## $ precip_daily         <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
## $ windspmax_daily      <int> 17, 32, 16, 12, 8, 13, 15, 21, 13, 12, 10, 14, 19, NA, 13, 10, 11, 15, 15, 10, 13, 13,...
## $ windspmaxdir_daily   <chr> "SW", NA, "WSW", "NW", "W", "WSW", "WSW", "W", "S", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "SSW", "SSW", ...
```

Also, read up on the changes to `rvest` and `xml2`. Switching to `read_html()` should be something you get into muscle memory (`html()` will go away at some point).

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option that uses only the `rvest` and `stringr` packages.  In case such as these all of the data is stored in the webpage it just needs to be extracted out.  The records are stored within { } with the first field name is "city".  This step requires some trail and error to locate the records in order to determine the structure/order  The str_locate_all function call performs this search in a non-greedy method.  Once this strings (records) are extracted, it is just a matter of parsing out the values from each field and creating the final data frame.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

#read web page
pg <- read_html("http://www.njweather.org/data/daily")

#find data of interest {"first field.*? }
#find data within brackets with the first field named city then any number of characters(.*) - not greedy(?)
#finds start and stop
recStartStop<-str_locate_all(pg, "\\{ \"city.*?\\}")[[1]]
#extract the records out from page
records<-str_sub(pg, recStartStop[,1]+1, recStartStop[,2]-1)

#replaces , within the string if necessary
#records<-gsub(", ", "_", records  )

#split and reshape the data in a data frame
records<-strsplit(gsub("\"", "", records), ',')
columnsNeeded<-length(records[[1]])
data<-sapply(strsplit(unlist(records), ":"), FUN=function(x){x[2]})
#if the number of fields is not consisten (columnsNeeded) this will error
df<-data.frame(matrix(data, ncol=columnsNeeded, byrow=TRUE))

#update column names
#name the column names
names(df)<-sapply(strsplit(unlist(records[1]), ":"), FUN=function(x){x[1]})
```

Hopefully the comments within the code explains each step clearly enough.